# "Print" background colors in PDF using Chrome

Tags: printing, google-chrome, chromium, pdf

I try to save a page as a PDF file but it loses the background colors. I figure this is a standard setting for a printer, but when I save as a PDF I prefer the background colors to stay. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm not sure it has any relation to Ubuntu... :)

Secondly, there may not be a good generic way to save a website page to PDF while keeping the background - think of pagination, page numbering, titles etc. Think of white text on dark background. In many cases the results won't look good - that's why browsers fall back to white background. Also, many sites use separate stylesheets for printing, which additionally remove elements which are not needed on paper - navigation, menus etc.

What you need is a way to make a *screenshot* of the whole page - this will preserve all detais of the page how you see it. There are plugins for Firefox to do this - I suppose there may be something for Chrome too.

The Firefox plugin I used is called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/)

[image: a sample screen grab]

Comment: OK thanks. But I in fact only need my table rows to have colors... which they have online but not in printed form. I know I can activate this in other browsers, but not in Chrome for some reason (sorry if this is no Ubuntu issue)...